# Dynamic image/animation combining

Tags: c#, image

I'm working on a solution for my new project (in C#). I'm trying to make a dynamic image/animation combiner (maybe later even work with video's, but that's not required atm).

So basically my program is reading a xml file with all kinds of instructions the user needs to do. In the xml file it is possible that for 1 instruction multiple pictures are needed. So when there are 2 or 3 pictures (the maximum amount of pictures is 4) they need to be combined to 1 picture so I can show that on the image object on the main form. Also it is important that the pictures keep there proportions so the image doesn't look deformed.

I found a solution with GDI+ but it isn't that good as I wanted it and runs pretty slow on a bit older computers. Also combining animations with normal images is a real pain and goes very slow!

Is there a faster/easier way to do this? Maybe WPF is a solution but I got no experience with this.

Thnx for any help in advance!

Comment: How would the images be combined?

Comment: Well it depends on the width and height of the image. If the images are very thin you can put the next to each other if there width is very big you put the under each other. For 3 images ofc this gives more posibilities. So first compair the images and then scale them and put them togheter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This questsion is open now for mor then a year but I found the solution some time ago so I will post it here in case it is usefull for somebody else.

The best way to do this was creating to set up a grid dynamic. And then fill up each element of the grid with the needed media (Video, Image, animated gif's and even Viewport3D from another xaml file). Creating a grid in code is really easy so it should be a good solution for everybody who wants to do this in WPF.